# How to acquire permits from one of multiple semaphores?

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I have multiple resources each controlled by its own semaphore. I would like to acquire any of these resources and hold its semaphore. This is like an OR operation on acquire: "acquire M permits from semaphore1 or semaphore2 or ... or semaphoreN." To be clear, all M permits must be acquired from exactly one semaphore.

I believe I want a method `acquire` like the following:

```
Semaphore acquiredSemaphore = acquire(4, semaphore1, semaphore2, semaphore3);
```

It should wait (or return immediately) until it acquires the permits from any semaphore, and it should return the semaphore (so I can release the permits to it later). I am open to using any combination of method, class, or design pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did not test it, though:

```
Semaphore acquire(int permits, Semaphore ... semaphores)  throws InterruptedException {
     Semaphore candidate = null;
     while (true) { // polling loop
         for (Semaphore semaphore: semaphores) {
             // attempt to aquire from next Semaphore in the list
             if (semaphore.tryAcquire(permits) {
                 return semaphore;
             }
             // choose the candidate semaphore with maximum available permits
             if (candidate == null || candidate.availablePermits < semaphore.availablePermits) {
                 candidate = semaphore;
             }
         }
         // now we have to wait some time
         // instead of plain sleeping, we wait on the most filled semaphore 
         if (candidate.tryAcquire(permits, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) {
             return semaphore;
         }
     }
 }
```